# My classifier gives 1.0 accuracy on ALL test data set (except wrong photos)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset

**Have:**

- Dataset: 115 color images with 256x256 size, all photos belong to *ONE class* (cartoon person).
- Classifiers: KNN and Random Forest Classifier.

Comment: I wanted to make a classifier to *predict ONE* cartoon person on some photo, so I've collected a dataset, digitized it and put it in the fit method of classifiers. So at first, I chose `SGDClassifier`, but it works only with 2 and more classes in the dataset. So then chose KNN and Random Forest Classifier.

**Problem:** when I try to test my ready classifiers, I got *1.0 score* on *EVERY photo* (i tested that 1 object, 1 another object (another cartoon person) and a photo of the black screen) and they all had 1.0 score anyway.

Can somebody help me please? : ( I am stuck on this 2 days already and don't see ways to solve it by myself, I watched many solutions, but none of them worked in my case.

**Dataset**:

- The shape of my dataset numpy array is **(115, 196608)** and (for example) one image in my dataset numpy array looks this:

[image]

- Dataset is a 2D array, because classifiers take only 1D or 2D arrays.

**Code:** it's not full, just for an example

```py
train_data_values = numpy.array([*115 photos*])
train_data_labels = numpy.array([*115 labels*])
# For fact, all my labels equal "1", there is no other value.

# Trying KNN
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

KNN_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(**{'n_neighbors': 16, 'weights': 'distance'})
KNN_clf.fit(train_data_values, train_data_labels)

test_im = cv2.imread(DATASET_IMAGES_DIRECTORY + "\\test\\" + "test2.png")

KNN_clf.predict_proba(test_im.reshape(1, 3*256*256)) # Returns array([[1.]])

# Trying Random Forest Classifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

RF_clf = RandomForestClassifier()
RF_clf.fit(train_data_values, train_data_labels)

test_im = cv2.imread(DATASET_IMAGES_DIRECTORY + "\\test\\" + "test.png")

RF_clf.predict_proba(test_im.reshape(1, 3*256*256)) # Returns array([[1.]])
```

**Comment:** I looked at images in my numpy dataset because I thought they can be bad digitized, but NO, they can be built easily from array to image.

P.S. Parameters for the KNN classifier are random, because I've been trying grid search for the best parameters, but there were again 1.0 scores everywhere.

Comment: If you only have one class, the probability gets dumped into that one class no matter what the photo is.  It has nowhere else to put it.

Comment: @Chris, oh... Thank you for your answer, what can i do this way? I just want to make a classifier for one cartoon person...

Comment: You cannot have a single class classifier this way.  You will need two classes at least, one with the character and one without.  Then the probability can be distributed between the two classes correctly.  It sounds like you are trying to do object detection, not image classification.

Comment: @Chris, but what do i need to take as the second class? The background without the cartoon person on it?

Comment: That would be a good starting point!

Comment: @Chris, oh object detection.. I didn't learn that yet xD. But anyway, thank you! Gonna try to add second class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All classifiers learn their scores from their training data. And scores of most classifiers (including random forest and KNN) have probabilistic meaning: they are tuned to reflect the probabilistic distribution of the training data as well as possible.

So if your training data consists of 100% of a single class, then the classifier will learn that with 100% probability any sample belongs to this class, and will predict this class with absolute confidence.

The lesson: to use *any* classifier, you need at least two classes, otherwise, the prediction will be more or less meaningless. My recommendation is to add negative samples, that is, samples without your target person, including:

- images with other persons from your and other cartoons
- images with background only and without persons
- images with some non-animated objects

There are a few exceptions, such as [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html), that are (presumable) capable of producing meaningful scores being trained on a single class. But whether they work adequately on your data, that you will never know, until you test them with data from several different classes.

Comment: Hello, @David Dale, can you say please, do i need two classes too in my object detection model (like YOLOV)?